# Unable to Browse Magento Setup Page

Tags: php, magento

I am working on Magento project everything is fine the icon of WampServer is green also the php admin working but I cannot browse Mangento Setup page Here is screen shot

**Screen Shots**

[Internal server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIisK.png)

[image: Internal server error]

and here is screen shot of magento running on localhost

[Magento running on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVpDv.png)

[image: Magento running on localhost]

I read the [article](http://blog.luutaa.com/uncategorized/how-to-overcome-500-internal-server-error-when-installing-magento/) here which says that change the file permission from 664 to 644 but there is no option to change such permissions.

Please help me to solve this error thankyou.

Comment: Try to change folder permissions from command line.

Comment: how can I do this please?

Comment: Open command prompt -> cd 'your Magento installation Directory' -> `chmod -R 777` app . Like wise alter permissions for media, var and whatever required.